# Internet connection in android emulator

Tags: android, connection, emulation

I have no idea, what am i doing wrong

I want to turn off internet connection in emulator (Android 2.2)

I'm pressing F8 -> no effect, i still have internet connection

I turn airplane mode -> no effect, i still have internet connection.

I go to settings for check, airplane mode is on, wifi is off, but there is internet connection on device.

What is wrong?!

Please, don't suggest to turn off internet on my computer. I know, it's the solution for sure, but not the best one

P.s.

It is probably the bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3838

I tried to disable connection in emulator for android 1.5 and it works fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably the bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3838

I tried to disable connection in emulator for android 1.5 and it works fine there.

Answer (score 5):

Open the **DDMS perspective** under Eclipse and set the **denied/unregistered value** for the voice and the data

Comment: It works on my emulator. I have no Internet connection at all.

Comment: Probably it's bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3838 But why it works for some people?!

Comment: Try to delete your simulator instance and to create a new one.

Comment: tried it on another way. Just created a new istance .. and ... it doesn't work. But then i opened the existing 1.5. instance .. there is no connection. And it's for the first time enough for me

Comment: and you are really using 2.2-emulator?

Comment: [Another way of doing it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3838#c15) : `telnet localhost 5554    // Connects to the emulator
qemu monitor             // Enter in the QEmu functionalities
info network             // List the network adapter "user.0" is usually the name
set_link user.0 down     // Shut the network down
set_link user.0 up       // Re-enable networking`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emulator console to set emulator speed to 0 (and also delay), but might not be exactly what you are looking for if you want the network to be completely DOWN.

```
 $ telnet localhost 5554
 network speed 0.01 0.01
 OK
 network delay 1000 1000
 OK
 network status
 Current network status:
   download speed:          10 bits/s (0.0 KB/s)
   upload speed:            10 bits/s (0.0 KB/s)
   minimum latency:  1000 ms
   maximum latency:  1000 ms
```

This causes most network connections to fail for me (but app still thinks network is UP).