# how do I change the network state over ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have an emulator that I want to simulate the loss of a data connection while in my app.  I have the receiver's setup correctly but I need a way to change the data connection via adb.

Is there an ADB command that turns off the data connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect to an emulator via telnet

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

once connected you can set the network speed.

```
network speed 0
```

or

```
gsm data off
```

maybe you find this link helpful.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console#querycontrol

Comment: What about a real device? telnet doesn't work. And after `shell` command, `network` and `telnet` commands not exist!

Answer (score 0):

From DDMS Perspective in Eclipse set denied/unregistered value for voice and data. 
It works in the Android Emulator 1.5.

---

Check out this thread: [Internet connection in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898949/internet-connection-in-android-emulator)